# counting the number of residues in a fasta file

Tags: awk

I have a fasta file which contains protein sequences. How can I count the number of residues in each sequence with awk?

```
>seq1
PESDFA
>seq2
>seq3
GFCSSWWR
```

Desired Output

```
 seq1  6
 seq2  0
 seq3  8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `awk` gives you some:

```
awk -v FS="" '!/^>/ {print f,NF} {f=substr($0,2)}' file
seq1 6
seq3 8
```

---

To get `seq2` you can do this:

```
awk '{printf (/^>/&&NR>1?RS:"")"%s ",$0} END {print ""}' file | awk '{print substr($1,2),length($2)}'
seq1 6
seq2 0
seq3 8
```

First part change all `seq` and info to one line, next part gives the length.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I should get seq2 as zero in the output.Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

this line is not nice, but works for your example:

```
kent$  paste f <(sed '1d' f)|awk '/^>/{print $1, ($2~/^>/?0:length($2))}' 
>seq1 6
>seq2 0
>seq3 8
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F'>' '
    NF==2 { seq=$2; lgth[seq]=0; next }
    { lgth[seq]=length($0) }
    END { for (seq in lgth) print seq, lgth[seq] }
' file
seq1 6
seq2 0
seq3 8
```

If you care about the order of output, just keep a separate array of `seq` values

```
$ awk -F'>' '
    NF==2 { seq=$2; seqs[++numSeqs]=seq; next}
    { lgth[seq]=length($0) }
    END { for (i=1; i<=numSeqs; i++) print seqs[i], lgth[seqs[i]]+0 }
' file
seq1 6
seq2 0
seq3 8
```